# How to analysis irregular results by discriminant analysis in R?

Tags: r, lda

I have learnt the use of LDA function in R to analysis regular results like this:

---

```
(x1&x2 are factors, G is classification)

X1 X2 G
2.95 6.63 1
2.53 7.79 1
3.57 5.65 1
3.16 5.47 2
2.16 6.22 2
```

---

Now my question is how to analysis the data if G are irregular results like (1.2;2.3;1.6...)

I also have learnt how I can get the scores of LDA, but I can't get it in QDA.
I had read the file of predict.qda and can't find the score option. Is this impossible in QDA?

This is my code:

```
C=read.table("clipboard",header=TRUE)
attach(T)
library(MASS)
ld=lda(G~x1+x2)
Z=predict(ld)
newG=Z$class
cbind(G,Z$x,newG)
```

Comment: Can you give us your code?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about the limits of a particular statistical method or possible alternatives. This is not a specific programming question that would be on-topic for Stack Overflow. Perhaps [stats.se] would be a more appropriate site.

Comment: @noahye what do you mean by "irregular results" ?